# Adding relative constraints the iOS layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to set relative constraints to layout elements like the image below:
[image]

1) the white square must be on the top right corner filling 50% of the horizontal content.
2) the central globe must be relative to the screen size. example: on 3.5 inch device must be smaller, on 5.5 must be greater. like 75% of the screen width.

Comment: Not sure about 1. but for 2. You need to set, Leading, Trailing, Top and bottom so that it can resize, but you will face problem because I guess its an image, and you may not get the correct aspect size for all screen size. so you need to set the imageview fill mode to aspectfit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0) Clear all constraints for sanity.

.
.

**1/4 SQUARE**

1) Resize your view to kind-of fit the intended size.

[image]

2) Select the square view and add margin constraints.

[image]

3) multiselect the root view and the view

[image]

4) Add equality constraint of width and height.

[image]

5) Select the equal height constraint and then the equal width constraint and change the multiplier to 2 for both constraints.

[image]

**DONE**

Answer (score 2):

0) Clear all constraints for sanity.

. .

**CIRCLE**

1) Put the circle view roughly into the middle.
[image]

2) Select it and add these two constraints.

[image]

3) This circle is a UIView which is a rectangle so it has width and height that are independent from each other....but we need to keep them equal..so we need to put an Aspect Ratio Constraint.

[image]

4) And finally ..we need to give it some size (width == height here). Let's make the size dependent on root view width. Multiselect again both the circle view and the root view..and add the equal width constraint. Also experiment with ratio. 1.6 looks good to me for a start.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I 've spent serious time making these screenshots so that is super clear how to do it and perhaps helpful to others too. So if you don't mind, as a courtesy please bump up both answers by +1 vote. Thanks :)